# How to quit Skype on Android?

Tags: skype

I'm using the newly released market version of Skype on my ADP1 running CyanogenMod 6.0.

I can't seem to **quit** the Skype program. There doesn't seem to be any mechanism for signing out of Skype once signed in. I can kill the task, but the next time anything triggers it it think it has the right to sign in and be online again, bar nothing. The task bar icon just takes you to the program, but the program doesn't seem to have any menus, doesn't respond the the back button etc.

Ideas?

Comment: All these solutions are for the previous version of Skype. v2 doesnt allow you to just quit the app. Must be a bug.

Comment: Obligatory: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GnFRk.jpg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With version 4.0 (released July 1, 2013), they've changed, once again, how to sign out.

Here's how to do it:

1. While logged in, tap your avatar in the top right corner
2. On your account profile, tap the Overflow Menu (three vertical dots) in the lower right corner

   - If your phone has a physical menu button, you'll use that
3. You now have the option to sign out

([source](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-sign-out-new-skype-40-android))

---

Skype has recently updated (10-July); one of the changes is to make it easier to sign out.

[Skype for Android 4.0 Update: We Heard You](http://blogs.skype.com/2013/07/10/skype-for-android-4-0-update-we-heard-you/)

> - You wanted an easier way to sign out. Now you can find this option by hitting the **Menu** key or on any of these navigation screens: **Recent**, **Favorites**, **People** and **Profile**.

Comment: I think it's noteworthy that this does not delete the stored credentials. If "Sign in automatically" is enabled, the next time you start Skype you will be signed in instantly.

Answer (score 27):

Go the to **MyInfo** tab and set your status to **Sign Out**.

Once you're signed out the back button works as expected and exits Skype.

**EDIT**: As of v2.9.0.315 (at least) Skype has simplified the log out mechanism:

In the home screen of Skype simply do this:

[image]

Comment: This no longer works as of Skype 4.0.0.17847 for Android.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I just found out how you can quit skype.
Go to the main screen in the app and click the left button.
After that click sign out, than you'll be able to quit with the return button.
Some have already posted this but I think it wasn't completely clear to people who are new to android (like me) :P

Answer (score 3):

For me 'Sign Out' behaves exactly as on the PC Skype client. i.e. the client keeps running. If you then force it to quit (see below) you will need to enter your password again next time you sign in.
Here is a generic way to quit Skype that does not require to install a new task manager or some 'stop skype' app:
Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> Skype -> Force stop

Comment: A few days ago I updated Skype and it used to start by itself even after I logged out properly. I did it several times and finally I used the option 'Force stop' in Settings-Applications and it resolved it. I think it is some bug in Skype or/and in Android (I have 4.0)

Answer (score 2):

They changed it again, it appears (Skype 4.4.0.31835). While previously it could be reached via the Menu button, there is no more option to sign out there.

[image: No sign out in Skype 4.4.0.31835 menu]

Instead now you have to press the button with the dashed circle around the avatar, next to the menu button on the main screen of Skype. There you'll see this:

[image: Location of Signout option]

At the very bottom you find the option to sign out, which will also quit the Skype client.

The previous version behaved the way described by [the accepted answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48422/9993) (as of this writing). But it didn't get me any further.

Comment: Confirmed, the only option to fully "quit" Skype is to manually "sign out". Also see [Skype showing me as online - after stopping app and even after device shutdown?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69891/)

Answer (score -1):

I know how to sign out. When you are signed in, HOLD THE HOME BUTTON FOR A LONG TIME ON YOUR ANDROID PRODUCT, NOT IN SKYPE! You will be able to see a button which is Task Manager. Click it and you will see the active applications on your android product. Then press the end button that you see next to the skype logo.

Comment: You must have a custom task manager app installed and bound to that key, that is not part of the base Android system. The task switcher in stock android just allows you to switch to RECENT applications, not close them and doesn't even indicate if they are still running or not.

Comment: This is only true for Touchwiz (Samsung) devices.