# How can I close Skype so that it stops running?

Tags: skype

I installed Skype on my wife's phone (HTC Desire), played a bit with it and then exited using the back button as suggested in other question. I can still see her account saying she is logged-in though. How can I exit Skype so that it really stops running?

Comment: On my N7 there is a button in the top right of the main screen which logs out an exits. Is that there on your phone?

Comment: Related: [How to quit Skype on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/how-to-quit-skype-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Skype app, press Menu -> Sign out, or use the Sign-out button on the top-right corner of the app's home screen, then confirm.

Answer (score -1):

Try signing out first. And than back button.

Comment: pressing the back button only stores it in the stack (keeps it running in the background)

Answer (score -1):

Well first off.  Theres no true way to stop it.  Secondly, The way I do it.  I sign out of skype first.  Then, i use the manage apps or task manager.  Stop the app first. Then, make sure it has been cleared from the cached background processes.  A phone restart might be required to start the app again or other apps.  I am fine with having to restart my phone.  It gives me the chance to control everything I do on it.