# Getting rid of stale notification icons in the notification _bar_?

Tags: notifications, nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean, notification-icons

How can I get rid of notification icons for Skype in particular, but any app in general when the app was killed using one of the many available task managers, but the notification icon still remains on the *notification bar* (that is the part that is persistent at the top of the screen in Jellybean)?

Device: Nexus 7 (2013), Android 4.3

Comment: What's wrong with just dismissing the notification in the usual way?

Comment: @DanHulme: hmm, perhaps my question is wrongly worded then. The problem is the tiny icon that sticks at the top even when the notification bar that can be pulled down further hasn't been pulled down. This kind of icon also shows with system updates. Only difference: you cannot dismiss this one, as there is no item in the pulled down notification bar to dismiss.

Comment: Why use task killers in the first place?  Any Android device running 2.2 and above should be able to manage its own memory properly.  Especially a modern device such as your 2013 Nexus 7.

Comment: To quit the latest version of Skype just tap the on-screen menu button (3 dots) from any Skype screen and choose the "Sign out" option.

Comment: @DanHulme it's not about notifications in the notification *area*, but those icons sticking in the notification *bar* (opposite to the connection indicators). To the OP: Why not simply use the Logout functionality of Skype? AFAIK that should not only remove the icon, but also "really quit" the app, so you wouldn't need to "kill" it. Please report back if that works: if so, I would make it an answer (currently it's just a guess, as I avoid NSA software as best as possible and thus cannot verify myself ;)

Comment: @Izzy: the actual problem turned out to be finding that option ;) ... see http://android.stackexchange.com/a/55077/9993 ... they keep changing where the Signout is. I'll leave the question, since I've had this with other programs in the past, so a solution is desirable regardless of the Skype issue being resolved now.

Comment: OK, so as this question is intended to be more general (concerning the "Service-is-Running" icons), it's about finding the similar option in all kind of apps? That would make it too broad to fit here. What kind of answer you're after, then? Solutions requiring root and working independent from the app in question accepted as well?

Comment: @Izzy: why is it too broad to answer if it's about *notification icons* in the *notification bar*. That's like saying a question about how to install an app from the Play Store is too broad. The *notification icons* are a common trait of apps and they can become stale, so what exactly makes the question how to get rid of stale icons "too broad"?

Comment: Because you "get rid of those icons" by closing the app correctly. So if we should describe that for every app that might place an icon there, it would be quite extensive. Of course the easy answer is: "close the apps correctly" (not shoot them down), because then they remove their icons themselves.

Comment: @Izzy: that's a silly remark. Obviously if I ask to get rid of *stale icons* I mean **stale** icons and that is a generic thing to do *after* the fact, i.e. when you have the stale icons. And I think it's warranted to ask for a solution other than a reboot. It is certainly technically possible there is something like an "icon swiper".