# Skype showing me as online - after stopping app and even after device shutdown?

Tags: skype, shutdown

**Scenario A:**

1. start Skype
2. do some other work
3. shut down the Android device

**Problem:**
My contacts are still seeing me as being "online".
Strangely enough there seems to be no `heartbeat` feature implemented in Skype.
So even after 1 day my contacts are trying to call me - even though the device is powered off.

Initially I thought this symptom would occur in case i forgot to manually quit the Skype app before shutting down the device.
So i was searching for an answer how to configure Skype to *automatically* log off / quit when the Android device is *shutting down*?

But now it turned out the situation is even worse:

***Scenario B:***

1. start Skype
2. do some other work
3. quit the Skype app
4. shut down the Android device

After step 3 I'm still listed as being "online".
When a contact sends me a chat message it pops up.
So it means: even though Skype no longer appears in the task manager it seems to be running as a `secret, invisible background task`!?

And after step 4 the behaviour is the same as in Scenario A. I'm not transitioning to "offline" state.

**Summary:**
There seem to be 3 problems:

- no heartbeat feature implemented in Skype
- quitting the Skype app is not properly terminating / signing off
- shutting down the Android device also is not influencing the online status

**The only thing that works for me so far:

You must switch to Skype, tap on your profile, at the very bottom *manually* do "sign out".**
That's just not bearable.

This is:
**Android 4.1.2**
**Skype 4.9.0.45564**
**Skype 5.0.0.49715**
**Skype 5.1.0.56619**
**Skype 5.1.0.58677**
**Skype 5.4.0.5871** (at least I'm now showing as being "Away" - instead of "Online")

2015-08-15 - the problem is back and it's even worse:
**Android 5.1.1**
**Skype 5.9.0.14047**
Even though I'm manually signing out, terminating the app and shutting down the Android device I'm still being shown as being "online"!!

--
All of the above tested @ Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (WiFi only) / GT-P3110

Comment: Stupid question, but you're not signed in somewhere else as well, are you?

Answer (score 10):

OMG, I have found the following posting: http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/Skype-invading-and-changing-people-s-online-status/m-p/2961695/highlight/true#M28546

According to above the "always on" concept was a *deliberate* decision by Microsoft:

```
(...) we have changed the way online status presence works:
(...) we are showing you as online to your contact even when you left or
force killed the app on your mobile phone (...)
```

They admit that certain scenarios need fixing:

```
Now we've identified a few scenarios where this is simply misleading:
 - you've switched off your device
 - you've disconnected from the internet (e.g. by switching to airplane mode
   and you are somewhere mid flight)

In these occasions you are right now still shown online and we are working to
make Skype presence indicator be meaningful in these scenarios as well.
```

This is just so weird.
They should certainly make it configurable.

**For now the only way to disconnect is to *manually* "sign out".**
Quitting the app isn't sufficient. Shutting down the device is neither.

*Status Update (2015-08-15):*
The problem is back. And it's even worse!
Even though i manually sign out, quite the Skype app and shut down the Android device I'm still being shown as "online"!
Observed with: Skype 5.9.0.14047 @ Android 5.1.1

Comment: Is there any progress about this in Android version recently? Windows Phone version is still the same, unfortunately :/

Comment: Android as well I'm afraid. I had created a test account on a test device a year go, then switched that off. Not used since. The test account (used nowhere else) is still reported being "online", though no activity took place with it ever since...

Answer (score 3):

Send any of Your contacts:

```
/showplaces
```

It will show You all devices currently online for this account:

```
 [18:47:36] System: You have 3 online endpoints:
    {25cf308c-73a9-ddfe-c6c7-c4a2507cf657}) my_desktop Linux Skype
    {e00a3a04-9ff8-1ad3-4b45-4a3a6d2caf95}) my_notebook Linux Skype
    {8440a849-0209-4ffb-25c8-c5bdbbe1035b}) localhost Android Skype
```

Then send:

```
/remotelogout
```

It shokld kick off all devices but current. Now check again by

```
/showplaces
```

It should now be only one connection in list:

```
 [18:50:32] System: You have 1 online endpoints:
    {25cf308c-73a9-ddfe-c6c7-c4a2507cf657}) my_desktop Linux Skype
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, thanks! Recently, even the manual sign out doesn't work. It says it signed me out but I get a notification and it starts up as soon as someone sends me a message.

Comment: /remotelogout not working on Mac /shoplaces works as advertised

Answer (score 0):

Each with a Skype account,  5 members of my family and I can confirm the efficacy and success of [the following](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-shows-offline-contacts-as-away/m-p/3871590/highlight/true#M335456) (which is the same as [this on Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230494)) that solved this problem:

> There is an easy way to fix the issue with contact appearing Away while they are actualy Offline. Just log in Skype, open a contact (whoever it is), try sending as an instant message this text:
>
> /remotelogout
>
> After that try sending this text:
>
> /showplaces
>
> And finally try sending this text again:
>
> /remotelogout
>
> You are ready, next time you go offline, you will appear as offline, not as away.